# Why isn't my USB-To-Serial Adapter Working?

Tags: macos, usb, serial-port, usbserial

I have a USB-to-Serial Adapter that is being recognized on my Mac in the System Information as being connected to the USB Hub but when I run ls /dev in Terminal the usbserial is not showing up. It was working up until this morning but now it is not. I have tried rebooting, changing USB slots and the lot. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after doing some research I have found that the Prolific driver that is designed for the USB-to-Serial adapter is a little unstable. Therefore I used a third party driver that seems to have fixed the problem 100%. You can find it here, http://xbsd.nl/2011/07/pl2303-serial-usb-on-osx-lion.html, I recommend it even if the Prolific driver seems to be working okay.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is arising almost every time in windows. and as a solution we go to devise manager->other device->right click on that->update driver software->browse my computer for driver software->Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer-> USB controller-> next.

Here my suggestion is to delete the driver from is the place and try to reboot you pc once and then check for the results. hope you get ride of this, best of luck.